# Refresh sorted tableview after core data is updated

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, sorting, core-data

I populate my tableview from core data. The rows are sorted according to a primary and a secondary keys. The viewDidLoad method contains the MOC and fetch request code.

Users can update the row in the tableview through a different view and the data is promptly updated as display. However the data displayed is now not in proper sorting order.

My problem is how do I get the data sorted and displayed accordingly? Should I invoke the viewDidLoad method again to re-fetch the data and then reload the tableview? What is the best way to do this? If I should invoke the viewDidLoad method, where should this be done?

My code is shown below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MonitorItem"];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"show"
                                                               ascending:NO],
                                  [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"expiry"
                                                              ascending:YES], nil]];

self.monitorItemArray = [[managedObjectContext
                          executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                          error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

}

Comment: Are you using `NSFetchedResultsController` ?

Comment: No, I don't. Can you show me how to?

Comment: Nope. But you can find a lot of info on Apple's developer website.

Comment: Apples own Xcode project template for Master-Detail Application with the core data box checked uses an NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: I have checked all the references and don't understand how to implement it. I am a beginner and still do not understand a lot of stuff. Perhaps what @fgeorgiew says is correct. I stored the objects in an array. The viewDidLoad method is appended above. I will have a look at KVO. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use FetchedResultsController then you mosts likely store the objects in some collection. You can then add observer (KVO - KeyValueObserving) to this collection to be notified when something changes in its objects. Then you can handle this response and invoke `[tableView reloadData];`

What you should not do is to invoke `viewDidLoad:` on your own. If you still think about it you should rather put your view initialization code into separate method which is called in the `viewDidLoad:` and you can then also use it when you need it.